# Add more button not working on my admin panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This code is working but by clicking on the button then the page reload automatically.So, the new div is not appeared. 
I can't find out what is the problem. Can you help me please.

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function newJacky() 
{
    var new1= "<p>one more added</p>";
    $(".apn").append(new1);     
}
</script>

<button onclick="newJacky()">Add New</button>
<div id="apn" class="apn"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This code is working but by clicking on the button then the page reload automatically (...)

From the above, I suspect that the `<button>` is placed inside a `<form>` element. That would explain why your page is reloaded after clicking the button.

An [example](http://jsfiddle.net/6h8bvd5n/) using your code with button placed inside form. This would not happen if the button is placed outside the form - [example](http://jsfiddle.net/6h8bvd5n/3/)

**Solutions**:

1. You can add a `type=button` attribute to the button (`type=submit` is by default if the attribute is not specified):

   ```
   <button type="button" onclick="newJacky()">Add New</button>
   ```

   [**DEMO 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/6h8bvd5n/1/)

   > `type` attribute of `<Button>` element. Possible values are:
   >
   > - **submit**: The button submits the form data to the server. This is the default if the attribute is not specified, or if the attribute is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.
   > - **reset**: The button resets all the controls to their initial values.
   > - **button**: The button has no default behavior. It can have client-side scripts associated with the element's events, which are triggered when the events occur.
   >
   > [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Attributes)
2. Prevent default form submission using [**`event.preventDefault()`**](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) (add `"my-btn"` class to the button):

   ```
   <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".my-btn").click(function(event){
           event.preventDefault();
           var new1= "<p>one more added</p>";
           $("#apn").append(new1);     
       });
   });
   </script>

   <button class="my-btn">Add New</button>
   <div id="apn" class="apn"></div>
   ```

   [**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/6h8bvd5n/2/)

Comment: Thank you. It's working now. I just added ' type="button" ' .

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting from the page using jquery is not specified as an elements class or div. Like below:

```
$("apn").append(new1);
```

This should either be `$(".apn").append(new1);` where you are getting an element with class apn, or `$("#apn").append(new1);` where you are getting an element with div apn.

try that

Comment: Thank you :) But page reloads automatically that's why this is not appeared after reloading.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery, I'd recommend using the on click functionality it provides:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.addNewBtn').click(function() {
            var new1 = '<p>one more added</p>';
            $('#apn').append(new1);     
        });
    });
</script>

<button class="addNewBtn">Add New</button>
<div id="apn" class="apn"></div>
```

Just make sure to add the class to the button.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Oceanity/x3azpt5z/)

Comment: If your page is reloading, it's another script that's triggering on the button being clicked.  Have you tried making the button  <input class="addNewBtn" type="button" value="Add New" />?  EDIT: Ah, I was beaten to that solution, that works.

Comment: Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: No problem, glad your issue was fixed.